# Ejecutar código vba en access desde excel

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

necesito ejecutar un módulo en access desde excel, el problema es que access ya se encuentra abierto, por lo tanto opencurrentdatabase() no me sirve, porque la base de datos ya está abierta

Comment: Si ya está abierta, la base estará asociada a un objeto. Mira dentro de ese objeto a ver si puedes ejecutar la macro o algo.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta, más bien la lo resolví justo de la manera que dices.